# Colocar inputs nos itens da lista para que possa ser adicionado e alterado os valores dos itens

Tags: react, react-native, react-hooks

Bom dia,

Estou estudando react e estou bem no inicio e pensei em ja começar fazendo um todo list, porem não quero por valores nos itens sem precisar ter que editar eles e assim somar com o total quem nem esta aqui a baixo [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem quando ele só fica assim quando já é predefinido e não estou conseguindo alterar e quando crio um novo o input o mesmo não permite que eu adicione um valor no campo, quando eu coloco o value={item.valor} para apresentar o valor do input, sem isso ele deixa eu alterar porem não salva nem vai para canto algum, vocês tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer para funcionar? utilizo onblur para quando eu clicar em outro canto ele adicionar o valor

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faChevronRight, faChevronLeft, faCircle, faCheckCircle, faPlus } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

const App = () => {
    // HINT: each "item" in our list names a name,
    // a boolean to tell if its been completed, and a quantity
    const [items, setItems] = useState([
        {itemName:'caneta', valor:2.30, quantity:3}, 
        {itemName:'caderno', valor:13.40, quantity:2}, 
        {itemName:'borracha', valor:1.2, quantity:5}
    ]);

    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
    const [totalItemCount, setTotalItemCount] = useState(0);
    const [valor, setValor] = useState(0);

    const handleAdd = () => {
        const newItem = {
            itemName: inputValue,
            quantity: 1,
            valor: 0.00,
            isSelected: false,
        };

        const newItems = [...items, newItem];

        setItems(newItems);
        setInputValue('');
        calculateTotal();
    };

    const handleEdit = (index) => {
        const newItems = [...items];

        newItems[index].valor = valor;

        setItems(newItems);
        calculateTotal();
    };


    const handleQuantityIncrease = (index) => {
        const newItems = [...items];

        newItems[index].quantity+=1;

        setItems(newItems);
        calculateTotal();
    };

    const handleQuantityDecrease = (index) => {
        const newItems = [...items];

        newItems[index].quantity-=1;

        setItems(newItems);
        calculateTotal();
    };

    const toggleComplete = (index) => {
        const newItems = [...items];

        newItems[index].isSelected = !newItems[index].isSelected;

        setItems(newItems);
    };

    const calculateTotal = () => {
        const totalItemCount = items.reduce((total, item) => {
            return total + item.quantity;
        }, 0);

        setTotalItemCount(totalItemCount);
    };
    

    var total = items.reduce(getTotal, 0);
    function getTotal(total, item) {
        return total + (item.valor * item.quantity);
    };

    return (
        <div className='app-background'>
            <div className='main-container'>
                <div className='add-item-box'>
                    <input value={inputValue} onChange={(event) => setInputValue(event.target.value)} className='add-item-input' placeholder='Adicione o produto...' />
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} onClick={() => handleAdd()} />
                </div>
                <div className='item-list'>
                    {items.map((item, index) => (
                        <div className='item-container'>
                            <div className='item-name' onClick={() => toggleComplete(index)}>
                                {item.isSelected ? (
                                    <React.Fragment>
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheckCircle} />
                                        <span className='completed'>{item.itemName}</span>
                                    </React.Fragment>
                                ) : (
                                    <React.Fragment>
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCircle} />
                                        <span>{item.itemName}</span>
                                    </React.Fragment>
                                )}
                            </div>

                            <div className='quantity'>
                            <div className='valor-item-box'>
                            R$ <input className='valor-item-input' placeholder='0,00' value={item.valor} onBlur={item.valor}/>
                            </div>
                                <button>
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronLeft} onClick={() => handleQuantityDecrease(index)} />
                                </button>
                                <span> {item.quantity} </span>
                                <button>
                                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faChevronRight} onClick={() => handleQuantityIncrease(index)} />
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <div className='total'>QTotal: {totalItemCount}</div>
                <div className='valor'>R$ {total.toFixed(2)}</div>
                

            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ! Para nos ajudar a tirar a sua dúvida, leia https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask e https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas?cb=1 ; Estes links irão te explicar como fazer perguntas. No seu caso, principalmente, coloque o código como texto no corpo da pergunta. Isso ajudará as pessoas a reproduzirem seu problema e resolver.

Comment: alguém sabe de algo?